# Scanning a text file and returning results

Tags: java, text, input, java.util.scanner

So, I'm still having wonderful problems with scanning Text files.

I'm currently doing the 'Baby names' project, a pretty common Ap computer science project, and working on getting it to return a few lines of text. The program does as follows, it asks the user for a name, and then it converts it to all caps. What it SHOULD do, is it should search the text document for an exact copy of the name, and then print the line. 
An example of how the text file is layed out:

```
MIREIO f Provencal Original Provenal form of MIREILLE
MIREK m Czech, Polish Short form of MIROSLAV and other beginning with the Slavic element   
mir "peace".
MIRELA f Romanian Romanian form of MIREILLE
MIRELE f Yiddish Yiddish form of MIRIAM
MIRELLA f Italian Italian form of MIREILLE
MIREMBE f African Means "peace" in Luganda.
```

So, if the program, found below, gets the input from the scanner "Mirek", What I'm trying to get it to do is convert it to MIREK(Done) And then return the rest of the text on the line with scanner.nextLine. And yet, every result I've had has said that no name could be found. If someone could help me with this logic error, I'd be very grateful.

Raw code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;//For reading the file.

public class BabyNamesProject {

//This program will use user input to scan several text documents for information regarding names.
//It will give the popularity of the name in the last few decades, it's meaning, and a Drawing Panel chart with it's popularity.
public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws FileNotFoundException {

    File f = new File("Names.txt");
    File g = new File("Meanings.txt");
    File h = new File("Names2.txt");
    Scanner nameCheck = new Scanner(f);
    Scanner meaningCheck = new Scanner(g);
    Scanner popularityCheck = new Scanner(h);
    Scanner Ask = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userName = "";
    String upperUserName = "";
    String meaning = "";

    System.out.println("Hello! This application will allow you to check how popular certain names are compared to others.");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Please type in your name!");
    userName = Ask.next();
    upperUserName = userName.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(upperUserName);

    if (meaningCheck.hasNext(upperUserName))
        System.out.println(meaningCheck.nextLine());
else
    System.out.println("Name was not found...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop. Your `if` statement only checks once

```
Scanner input = Scanner(System.in);
String name = input.nextLine();
String upperUserName = name.toUpperCase();

Scanner namesScanner = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));

while (namesScanner.hasNextline()){
    String line = namesScanner.nextLine();

    if (line.contains(upperUserName)){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
System.out.println("Name was not found...");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this always spit out a Name not found though, regardless of if it was found or not?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [javadoc for hasNext(pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29). It's job is not to search the file. All that it is supposed to do is check if the pattern matches the next token. In this case, all you are doing is checking if the first name in the file is `upperUserName`, and usually that's not true.

If you actually want to search all the lines in the file then you will need to do that yourself by creating a loop and considering each line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You only check the first line of your file here:

```
if (meaningCheck.hasNext(upperUserName))
    System.out.println(meaningCheck.nextLine());
else
   System.out.println("Name was not found...");
```

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
boolean inputExists = false; //boolean flag determining whether your input exists.
while ( meaningCheck.hasNext() ) //while there are more lines
{
  String currentLine = meaningCheck.nextLine();
  if (currentLine.contains(upperUserName))
  {
    System.out.println(currentLine);
    inputExists = true; //The message "Name not found" should not appear because something is found
  }
}

if ( !(inputExists) ) //If it does NOT exist
{
  System.out.println("Name was not found");
}
```

Comment: Personally, this is the solution I would use, except for one thing. Some definitons include other names in them as well, for instance, if you search "DANIEL" on the list, you'll find other names like "DEINIOL m Welsh Welsh form of DANIEL". Is there anyway to make it just print the exact line with the exact text?

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, the only input you would like to check are the names that each line starts with. So you want to check: Mirek, Mirela, Mirele but not Mireille, Miriam ##unless## there is a line below that actually starts with Mirreille, Miriam. If that's the case, you should replace `currentLine.contains(upperUserName)` with `currentLine.startsWith(upperUserName)`. Or have I misunderstood your comment?